# Wait for async calls to return before exiting program when using AWS-cpp-sdk

Tags: c++, multithreading, amazon-web-services, asynchronous

I am doing a POC on using the AWS-cpp-sdk
For which I wrote a simple program to send messages to the SQS queue.

I am using the SendMessageAsync method to send the messages like below.

`sqsClient->SendMessageAsync(sendMessageRequest, &sendMessageCallBack);`

My program crashes since my program is exiting before the async method returns and `Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);` terminates the threads created by the Async method call.

I found that the AWS-sdk for JAVA suggests the following for exactly this scenario. 
`

```
/**
 * Shuts down the client, releasing all managed resources. This includes
 * forcibly terminating all pending asynchronous service calls. Clients who
 * wish to give pending asynchronous service calls time to complete should
 * call getExecutorService().shutdown() prior to calling this method.
 */
@Override
public void shutdown() {
    super.shutdown();
    executorService.shutdownNow();
}`
```

I am unable to find something equivalent in the AWS cpp SDK. 
Can someone suggest what would be the best way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are responsible for making sure your requests are done before calling ShutdownAPI(). This is usually only an issue in contrived "sample app" sorts of scenarios where you are performing the operation directly inside your main() function. You also need to make sure the SQS client is deleted before ShutdownAPI is called.

On option is to use a `std::condition_variable`(semaphore) to synchronize before the exit. You can pass the semaphore to your callback and `notify_one()` at the end of the callback. Then, before shutdown you can call `wait()` on the semaphore.